# Problem with installing a module

Tags: drush

I need to import a new config without some files because when I try to install the profile module it says that `profile.type.main`, `system.action.profile_delete_action`, `system.action.profile_publish_action`, `system.action.profile_unpublish_action` already exists in the current config and this doesn't allow me to install that module

Comment: One way to do is delete all the existing configurations which ever blocking you to install your module and try to re-install again.

Comment: Is this about Drupal 5, or any release above it. Also, who or what is "cuz"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Drupal console commands to delete the existings configs. New install will only be possible when the existing configs are deleted.
use Drupal config:delete active profile.type.main

If you dont have drupal console installed then deleting the configs from db is other work around for this issue.

Go to the config db table and delete the configs which are existing.

Thank you